# Socket IO V0.7: Where to put flashsockets SWF file?

Tags: javascript, flash, websocket, socket.io

I currently have my 'WebSocketMain.swf' file sitting in the same directory as 'socket.io.min.js' but Firefox doesn't seem to want to use flash sockets. It always reverts to XHR-Polling. See test case here : http://thebeer.co/labs/rt/test.php (page is blank, check JS console for feedback).

**Is this the right place for it?**

**Do I need to direct Socket.io to the location of this SWF file?**

**UPDATE:**

My node server requesting minified client js.

```
var $ = require('jquery'); 
var http    = require('http'),
    url     = require('url'),
    https   = require('https'),
    fs      = require('fs'),
    crypto  = require('crypto'),
    io      = require('../'),
    sys     = require(process.binding('natives').util ? 'util' : 'sys'),
    server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.end();
    });

server.listen(80,"173.201.181.56");
var io = io.listen(server), buffer=[];
io.set('browser client minification', true);//<<minified client js requested here.
```

My client side including the minified JS:

```
<script src="http://173.201.181.56:60/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see that you decided to host the file your self. Did you know that Socket.IO also serves the client for you? See https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/How-do-I-serve-the-client

You can even configure it, so it outputs a minified build: https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO

This client also knows where the location of the .swf file is, so you don't need to configure anything.

If you still want to serve the file your self (which is not recommended) You need to set the `window.WEB_SOCKET_SWF_LOCATION` to `http://yoururlhere.com:port/socket.io/static/flashsocket/WebSocketMain.swf` or WebSocketInsecure.swf (this depends if you go cross domain or port, but the bundled socket.io client handles this already for you)

Comment: Wow thanks, didn't even know that was possible! Is there going to be a full documentation write up at some stage? As a beginner I'm finding it really hard to find information on all the Socket IO methods and techniques. The examples on git are currently very brief and leave a lot unexplained if you are new to this stuff...

Comment: During my research I heard from @Guille that flashsockets are being depreciated and are not longer served by default. Are the other transports better?

Comment: The documentation is scattered over various of place, you got the socket.io website (http://socket.io) the Readme.md files in the Github repositories and the wiki.


As for the flashsocket, we disabled it by default instead of deprecating it as there are some good use cases for using this transport. But it can take a bit longer to initialize than XHR polling. So there are some tradeoffs.